# Regex to exclude all content inside square brackets but not the square bracket content inside curly brackets

Tags: python

I have a list which has a set of strings-

```
mylist = ['abc','[apple','banana','cucumber]','efg','{','egg','[fff]','ginger }','end;','abc1','[','apple1','banana1','cucumber1',']','efg1','{','egg1','[fff1]','ginger1 }','end1;']
```

Combining all strings together to apply regex to exclude content inside square brackets :

```
newlist = ['|'.join(mylist)]

Output newlist : ['abc|[apple|banana|cucumber]|efg|{|egg|[fff]|ginger }|end;|abc1|[ |apple1|banana1|cucumber1|]|efg1|{|egg1|[fff1]|ginger1 }|end1;']
```

Using regex to element square bracket contents -

```
newlist1 =[re.sub('\[.+?\]','',newlist[0])
Output of newlist2- ['abc||efg|{|egg||ginger }|end;|abc1||efg1|{|egg1||ginger1 }|end1;']
```

It is eliminating the square bracket content inside curly brackets also..

```
Expected output : ['abc||efg|{|egg|[fff]|ginger }|end;|abc1||efg1|{|egg1|[fff1]|ginger1 }|end1;']
```

Comment: Regular expressions are probably not the right tool for this job. Detecting nested syntax is very hard to do with regex, since the languages defined that way are often not "regular" (which has a specific meaning in this context). Perhaps you should do some processing on your list of strings before joining them, or write your own code to iterate over the string and figure out what characters to omit.

Comment: Regex cannot balance brackets. You need to use real parsing techniques, which is too broad of a topic for a Stack Overflow answer. Please try putting e.g. `python text parsing` into a search engine.

Answer (score 1):

Though it's not exactly the answer you asked for, I hope it will help you. At first I preprocess the text, then I apply a regex.

```
import re
def preprocess(text):
    CurluBrace=False
    for i in range(len(text)):
        c=text[i]
        if c=='[' and CurluBrace==False:
            text=text[:i]+'`'+text[i+1:]
        if c==']' and CurluBrace==False:
            text=text[:i]+'`'+text[i+1:]
        if c=='{':
            CurluBrace=True
        if c=='}':
            CurluBrace=False
    return text
        


def main():
    text='abc|[apple|banana|cucumber]|efg|{|egg|[fff]|ginger }|end;|abc1|[ |apple1|banana1|cucumber1|]|efg1|{|egg1|[fff1]|ginger1 }|end1;'
    processedText=preprocess(text)
    newlist1 =[re.sub('\`.+?\`','',processedText)]
    print(newlist1)
```

A more Elegent Solution:

```
import re
def preprocess(text):
    CurlyBraceContext=0
    for i in range(len(text)):
        c=text[i]
        if CurlyBraceContext<=0:   
            if c=='[' or c==']':
                text=text[:i]+'`'+text[i+1:]
        if c=='{':
            CurlyBraceContext+=1
        if c=='}':
            CurlyBraceContext-=1
    return text
        
def main():
    text='abc|[apple|banana|cucumber]|efg|{|egg|[fff]|ginger }|end;|abc1|[ |apple1|banana1|cucumber1|]|efg1|{|egg1|[fff1]|ginger1 }|end1;'
    processedText=preprocess(text)
    newlist1 =[re.sub('\`.+?\`','',processedText)]
    print(newlist1)
```

Comment: Thanks Akash.. seems to work..
also can u help me out to understand how exactly this Curlybraces == False/True is working in the code..little confused here..

Comment: when there is a '{' in text, it means we are entering  {} curlybraces. when there is a '}', it means we are leaving curlybraces context .

Comment: So when *curlynace==False*, it means we are not in curlybraces. so we then change the *[]* -> *``*.

Comment: It's not a correctness issue, but I'd always prefer `not CurlyBrace` to `CurlyBrace == False`.

Comment: @Blckknght i am sorry for that. Actually i am more of a c++/c#/js/java programmer.